# Unable to compile ramdisk with libcryptsetup in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, clang++, android-build, android-make

I am trying to leverage cryptsetup functionality in a custom ramdisk image via AOSP. I would like to call cryptsetup to interact with a specified location during the early-init process of booting. I have downloaded https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/cryptsetup/ to my /external/ directory, afterwards I added #include <libcryptsetup.h> into my system/core/init/first_stage_init.cpp file, at the bottom right before the call to

```
execv(path, const_cast<char**>(args));
```

I then edited my system/core/init/Android.bp file cc_binary init_first_stage section and added

```
    include_dirs: [
        "external/cryptsetup/lib",
        "external/",
        "external/cryptsetup",
    ],
```

This allowed the include statement

```
#include <libcryptsetup.h>
```

to work fine and I can compile. However if I try to use functionality, for example as a test:

```
struct crypt_device *cd = NULL;
crypt_free(cd);
```

I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `crypt_free'
```

I am now running into linking issues.

I have tried adding libcryptsetup,cryptsetup,and other variations to
`shared_libs,system_shared_libs,static_libs`

I have also tried adding `-lcrypsetup` to the `cflags` array. All with no luck, usually resulting in the error:

```
error: -lcryptsetup: 'linker' input unused [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

I have also tried calling to execv to see if I would be able to call the cryptsetup binaries rather than using the libcryptsetup API, however, no calls to execv other than the call to init seem to be executed. I assume it has to do with SELinux polcies. Information in regard to how I can successfully interact with cryptsetup at early-init would be appreciated. Please provide full file paths (ex not just Android.mk but the full path to it) and direct location references as I am new to the AOSP environment. My build environment is Linux computer 5.19.0-43-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I am building for android bramble arm64 currently.